# xcode 4 cannot create a local repository

Tags: xcode, git

When ticking the "Create local repository for this project" in Xcode 4, I get a dialog box that says:

> "Cannot create a local repository.
>
> The git command line tool is required. Check the SystemTools checkbox in the Xcode Installer to do so."

Do I need to re-install Xcode or is there a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is telling you, you need to install the command line tools for Xcode 4 which includes the git binaries.

**Edited to add**

Also - Xcode installs and expects to find a git installation in /usr/bin/git and this causes problems if you already have Git installed, as it isn't seen. I wrote a script to to replace Xcode's git installation with symlinks to your own installation which is on [github here](https://gist.github.com/774277).

Remember to edit it with the correct location of Git on your computer.

Comment: OK, I already had git installed hence the confusion. Presumably the Xcode Installer installs its own version of git. Anyway, re-running the Installer fixed the problem.

Comment: Also Xcode's git integration is fairly half-assed. I recommend using git from the command line or another more mature tool (google "Tower 2").